# How to shorten component in file name? rename heroes.component.ts to heroes.xx.ts

Tags: angular, angular-components

I use VS Code with Angular. Is there any way to shorten the names of the copmponent files? `.component.` is way too long. It takes too much space.
I have e.g. `heroes.component.ts` and `heroes.component.html`. I would like to rename it to `heroes.comp.ts` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming multiple files with a single shot iscalled batch renaming. This can't be done from within Visual Studio Code.

When it comes to angular, As this rename command is not there in angular-cli, deleting the created angular component, directive, etc and again running the command to create the component is really pain.

Comment: One can 'rename' the prefix.I thought one might rename 'component' too. 'comp' would be ok too.